# Internet Explorer restrict multiple tabs

Tags: internet-explorer, tabs, duplicates, restrict

I have seen a nice example on Microsoft website details about how we can identify and restrict multiple tabs in internet explorer for a web application. The author mentioned about air line ticket example. You bought a ticket in one tab and perform some other action on a different tab. For some reason, I am not able to find it now.

For a web application, I want my users to know that there is already a tab opened and they will not be able to process in the second tab now?

Could anyone suggest ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use showModalDialog to display a modal window that the user can't navigate away form...(not recommended as webkit has depreciated support for)... or use a jQuery popup dialog (positioned div) that modally display a positioned div on top of the current page.
or

use a named window argument in your window.open call

eg. var win=window.open('newbooking.aspx','bookingstab',null,true);

(note: newbooking.aspx must be in the same domain and in the same IE security zone (default internet)) as outcomes of scripted Windows (window.open, showModalDialog or showModeless dialog) depend on the browser Security settings and popup blocker settings.

there are also named Windows constants in js.... _blank, _self, _top

that you can use for the target attibutes of base and <a> tags.

you can use target constant value of _self to force navigation only in the current tab.

depending upon your server side language you could also use a server varible to keep count of the number of webpages with a particular address are opened on the sessionID of the users session.